# What's the NodeJS / Express equivalent to PHP's file_get_contents('php://input')?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, typescript, express

In PHP I can fetch incoming JSON from let's say an AJAX request by calling `file_get_contents('php://input')`, I'm now rebuilding my API in NodeJS (TypeScript) and am looking for an equivalent to fetch incoming JSON.

Various web searches did not deliver what I was looing for, so I hope to find help here.

Comment: There are some JS equivalents of a lot of PHP functions in https://github.com/locutusjs/locutus/tree/master/src/php

Comment: listen to `req.on("data"` build out a string on data

Answer (score 1):

You can use bodyparser for express and receive data via post.

```
let app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.listen(port);
console.log('API started port' + port);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/path', "maybe cors()", function(req, res){
let data = req.body.data //data is the json you get
}
```

Thats the way i fetch json that gets send to the server. Hope you can make something with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the correct URL by using Axios. Following this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios for more.